# OLE2 command for returning the number of columns in an Excel file

Tags: excel, oracle11g, ole

Do we have an OLE2 command that can be used in Oracle Forms to return the number of columns in my excel file?! 
I want to open an excel file from Oracle Forms and go through all columns and then just some the colomns.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this I use a trivial solution, I iterate through all the col until the first empty one in the first line. Of course my file have always have the first row's col filled.

When I have a non filled row I use a constant, manually defined...

I iterate through like this:

```
Variant ws = /*(set your worksheet here)*/;
int col = 1;

for (int col = 1; toString(ws.olePropertyGet("Cell", row, col).olePropertyGet("value")) != ""); ++col)
    //do stuff ++count;
```

It is dirty, but I never found a better way to do this, and I will follow this question to find a new one.